# How can I enable admin to destroy the record when using CanCan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

My current code is just like this.
Only the user who posted can destroy his own records.
But I want to enable admin(user.id=1) to delete all the records.

How can I change this? also view? any smart way?

**/models/ability.rb**

```
def initialize(user)
    if user
        can :read, :all 
        can [:create, :destroy], Comment, {:user_id => user.id}
        can [:destroy], Comment, {:commentable_id => user.id, :commentable_type => user.class.name}
        can [:create, :update], Community, {:user_id => user.id}
    else
        can :read, :all 
    end
end
```

**View**

```
<%= link_to 'x', polymorphic_path([@user, comment]),
    :data => { :confirm => 'Do you want to delete?' },  
    :method => :delete, :disable_with => 'Deleting', 
    :remote => true, 
    :class => 'close'
if current_user && current_user.id == comment.user_id || current_user && current_user.id == comment.commentable_id %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need. BTW it is bad idea to use `user.id == 1` to check for admin rights, probably better solution is to add boolean `admin` field to `User` model. If you don't want to do it, you can replace `if user.admin?` with `if user.id == 1`.

```
def initialize(user)
  guest_ability
  user_ability(user) if user
  admin_ability if user.admin? # or `if user.id == 1` if you don't want to add `admin` field
end

private

def admin_ability(admin)
  can [:destroy], Comment
end

def user_ability(user)
  can :read, :all 
  can [:create, :destroy], Comment, { :user_id => user.id }
  can [:destroy], Comment, { :commentable_id => user.id, :commentable_type => user.class.name }
  can [:create, :update], Community, { :user_id => user.id }
end

def guest_ability
  can :read, :all
end
```

In your view:

```
<% if can? :destroy, comment %>
  <%= link_to 'x', polymorphic_path([@user, comment]),
        :data => { :confirm => 'Do you want to delete?' },  
        :method => :delete, :disable_with => 'Deleting', 
        :remote => true, 
        :class => 'close' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your ability file, you should make a distinction betyween the various roles a user can have, so you should add something like

```
if user.has_role? :admin
  can :destroy, Comment
end
```

In your view, instead of "doing al the work yourself", as you're doing now, you should use the can? method, as follows

```
if can? :destroy, comment
```

Using can? will use the directions you've described in your ability file. As simple as that!